# Hogan.js distributable file

Tags: node.js, makefile, hogan.js

Does anyone know how to get a hogan.js 3.0.0 dist file?

The files at https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js are source files that should be compiled with Node.js in order to create the distributable. My question is how to build the source files with Node on Windows, or a link to a pre-built distributable file.

The dist file is mentioned here: https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/master/lib/hogan.js#L16

Comment: I use hogan 3.0.0, get it with the git url with npm; as for the building, there is nothing to build, and if you mean hulk, its a javascript file with an env header for linux, just run it with node like any other javascript file

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm referring to the file at https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/blob/master/lib/hogan.js#L16 comment says "See dist/ for browser files" but there is No dist folder.  there is web folder which only contains older versions, and I am not familiar with Node.js -- therefore I am looking for a pre-built hogan.js file.

Comment: I see, you can use a grunt task to automate that for you: https://github.com/automatonic/grunt-hogan, 

or just run the command manually: EXAMPLE: hulk --wrapper amd ./templates/*.mustache (just run hulk from the commandline to see its options), 

and also you can in your code run: hogan.compile(fileContents, {asString: true}) giving you the parsed template as a string back, with that you'll need the Hogan.Template file, (this is the way i do it), the compiling of a template is the most work. I think the reference to that /dist is a leftover from the 2.* version, the github one is 3.0.0

Comment: Thanks again Paul.  as mentioned I am not familiar with these technologies (grunt/hulk/etc) but I am familiar with JS so there has to be an easier way to get that file.  having said that -- I would have gladly accepted your answer if this question hadn't been "put on hold".  unfortunately some users here are really bored...

Answer (score 1):

Hogan uses a Makefile to create dist builds and do testing. This can be envoked by running `make dist` from a NIX terminal. https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/156

If you want to avoid using the Makefile, because you are running node.js from a Windows command prompt or for whatever reason, you need to create a ./dist directory in Hogan's root directory where the package.json is, then run `node tools\release.js`.

Make sure you've installed the dev-dependencies with `npm install` in the same directory as the package.json first.